# Why does ASP.NET TreeView node expanding not work on postbacks?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, treeview

I am populating an ASP.NET (VB) TreeView with data from a database.  While populating the tree, I programmatically expand specific nodes based on their data.  The node expansion is completed correctly when called for non-postbacks but ***not*** for postbacks after a button click.  I am thinking that the page lifecycle is resetting the formatting somehow on button postbacks.  Does anyone know how I can populate the TreeView nodes with formatting intact for button postbacks?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

  'Formatting intact
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
      loadTreeView("MyTree")
    End If

  'Formatting not intact
    If Page.IsPostBack Then
      loadTreeView("MyTree")
    End If


End Sub

'Formatting not intact
Public Sub btnLoadHierarchy_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLoadHierarchy.Click
  loadTreeView("MyTree")
End Sub

<asp:Button ID="btnLoadHierarchy" runat="server" Text="Load Hierarchy"/>

<asp:TreeView ID="HierarchyTree" runat="server">
</asp:TreeView>
```

Comment: Are you certain that `Public Sub btnLoadHierarchy_Click` is running when you expect it to run?  Post the code that defines the button...

Comment: @TonyHinkle Well, I have also updated the code to show that the tree also does not keep the correct formatting if the code is in the page load section on non-postbacks.  So the issue seems to be with a different page lifecycle of postbacks.

Comment: Your `If Page.IsPostBack Then` condition will never be true, because it only gets evaluated If Not Page.IsPostBack is true.  You need to move one of the `End If` statements to be above that line.

Comment: @TonyHinkle sorry, that was a cut and paste fail.  I have updated the code with the correct syntax.

Comment: You need to handle the TreeView's TreeNodeExpanded and TreeNodeCollapsed events to save the state, maybe in viewstate,then restore it on postback

Comment: @fernan I believe the issue is that a postback page lifecycle event is causing the tree to lose all tree node expansion data.  So when the page loads for the first time, the tree node expansion is in tact, but when it is re-loaded it seems like the viewstate removes this node expansion.  I have tried disabling the viewstate for this control with no luck.  Because of this, I don't believe that handling the TreeNodeExpanded and TreeNodeCollapsed events will solve the issue.

Comment: @eniacAvenger have you tried removing the code that loads the treeview from within your button event? simply let the page load handle the treeview re rendendering if needed.

Comment: @fernan yes and unfortunately the same problem occurs

Comment: @eniacAvenger it has to do with the page life cycle. Please try to bind treeview Page_Init.       protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        loadTreeView("MyTree");        
    }